# How can I resolve this Pyart Issue with "Time" as the keyError from the data?

Tags: python

```
          KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
           <ipython-input-17-e0d335b3929e> in <module>()
            1 numfile = 0
            2 filename = os.path.join(data_dir, Directory[0])
---->       3 radar = pyart.io.read(filename)
            4 display = pyart.graph.RadarMapDisplay(radar)

       1 frames
      /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyart/io/cfradial.py in read_cfradial(filename, 
      field_names, additional_metadata, file_field_names, exclude_fields, include_fields, 
       delay_field_loading, **kwargs)
    
            134     # 4.4 coordinate variables -> create attribute dictionaries enter code here
            135     time = _ncvar_to_dict(ncvars['time'])
            136     _range = _ncvar_to_dict(ncvars['range'])
            137 

          KeyError: 'time'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this with a specific solution unless you can provide a little more detail. The basis of this error, however, is that the reader `pyart.io.cfradial` is looking for a specific variable in the provided NetCDF but cannot find it. One simple solution might be to directly specify a "time" variable using either `NetCDF4.Dataset` or `xarray`, which might allow the file to be opened, if there are no other missing variables.

It is also possible that a specific file handler in Pyart could open your NetCDF file; take a look at [pyart.io](https://arm-doe.github.io/pyart/API/generated/pyart.io.html) and [pyart.aux_io](https://arm-doe.github.io/pyart/API/generated/pyart.aux_io.html) for listings of available functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to follow your suggestions. However, what more detail would you want? Do I have to rename the files to contain time stamps?

Comment: In terms of what more detail I would want: I would want to know the structure of the netcdf file. Netcdf files are not opinionated about the variable and dimension names of the underlying data. Therefore, any netcdf file reader must know what to expect about the file. Where did you get this Netcdf file? What is the data's schema? Have you attempted any of the other Netcdf file readers available in Pyart that I suggested?

Comment: The netCDF file is from an X-Band Radar. Yes, I have tired those Pyart libraries to read the file but I got other type of Keyword Errors. In the past, I have been able to read and plot other netCDF files with different structures from other radar bands that are not Xband. This file is in the format: rjy21328144655.nc

Comment: Try to use Python's NetCDF4 library to list the variables that are available in your netcdf file, then post what the variables are. I suspect that there may be a "time" variable under a different name. If that is the case, you will have two options: 1) write your own reader file to produce a `radar` object in pyart, or; 2) rename (or derive) a "time" variable in the dataset that matches the format pyart expects. Also, can you edit your question to include a link to an example netcdf that exhibits this problem?